# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'pop' - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this method, which is a button:

```
@api.multi
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    vat = self.vat.upper()
    res = {
        'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
        'vat_subjected': False,
        'vat': vat,
        'wh_iva_agent': False,
        'wh_iva_rate': 0.0
    }

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    # assumption: both methods in new api style
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat): 
        res = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat)  
    self.write(res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

It should return the NIF of a `res.partner`, bt every time I click on it, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/search_info_partner_seniat.py", line 65, in search_partner_seniat
self.write(res)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3518, in write
vals.pop(field, None)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

The error comes here:

```
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat): 
        res = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat) 
    self.write(res)
```

I don't know if these two models might be the cause, they are working fine as I recall, on partner:

```
@api.model
def check_vat_ve(self, vat): #, context=None
    """ Check Venezuelan VAT number, locally called RIF.
    RIF: JXXXXXXXXX RIF VENEZOLAN
         IDENTIFICATION CARD: VXXXXXXXXX
         FOREIGN IDENTIFICATION CARD: EXXXXXXXXX
    """

    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        return True
    if re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8}|[D][0-9]{9})$', vat):
        return True
    return False
```

On `seniat_url`:

```
@api.multi
def _dom_giver(self, vat): 
    """ Check and validates that the vat is a passport,
    id or rif, to send information to SENIAT and returns the
    partner info that provides.
    """
    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    name = ''
    url_seniat = ''

    url_obj = self.search([], limit=1) #self.browse(self.search([]))#[0] #(cr, uid, self.search(cr, uid, []))[0]
    #url1 = url_obj.name + '%s' %(value or '')
    #url2 = url_obj.url_seniat + '%s' %(value or '')
    if url_obj.name:
        name = url_obj.name

    if url_obj.url_seniat:
        url_seniat = url_obj.url_seniat
    url1 = name + '%s'
    url2 = url_seniat + '%s'
    vat = self._validate_rif(vat) #cr, uid, vat, context=None
    if vat:
        return self._get_rif(vat, url1, url2) #cr, uid, vat, url1, url2, context=context
    else:
        return False
```

Any ideas?

These are methods migrated from v8 to v10 community.

Comment: check whether the res has a value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the write you should define which fields you want to write the value to.
so res must be a dictionary. When you replace that dictionary for something else like the False from your method call it won't be able to write that as a dictionary.

I suggest that you use `res.update({'dom' : self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat) }`)
replace 'dom' with the variable you'd like to set

if the result could also be a dict you could use the following:

```
update_vals = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat)
if update_vals:
    res.update(update_vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

res could be False when function _dom_giver return False. You should check if res is not False before calling write method.